# Finance google infoquote all explained?

Tags: json, api, finance, google-finance

I am fiddling around with google finance API and do not understand all keys in the reply. Can anyone comment them for me? I googled around, picked up here and there and guessed around afterwards. See below:

I was not able to post JSON in a human readable format so pastebin. Here is my code:

```
http://www.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&infotype=infoquoteall&q=ETR:ADS
{
Ident:              "id": "667567",
Symbol              "t": "ADS",
exchange            "e": "ETR",
Lasttrade Price?    "l": "153.00",
??                  "l_fix": "153.00",
Lasttrade Currency? "l_cur": "153.00",
??                  "s": "0",
lasttrade?          "ltt": "10:22AM GMT+1",
lasttrade?          "lt": "Feb 22, 10:22AM GMT+1",
lasttrade?          "lt_dts": "2017-02-22T10:22:49Z",
change              "c": "+0.95",
change_abs          "c_fix": "0.95",
change_perc         "cp": "0.62",
perc_abs            "cp_fix": "0.62",
??                  "ccol": "chg",
??                  "pcls_fix": "152.05",
??                  "eo": "",
delay of quote      "delay": "15",
open                "op": "151.75",
high                "hi": "153.45",
low                 "lo": "151.45",
volume              "vo": "105,247.00",
??                  "avvo": "578,084.00",
52week              "hi52": "160.30",
52week              "lo52": "95.17",
market_cap?         "mc": "32.01B",
??                  "pe": "31.64",
??                  "fwpe": "",
??                  "beta": "",
??                  "eps": "4.84",
count shares?       "shares": "200.31M",
??                  "inst_own": "",
name                "name": "adidas AG",
type                "type": "Company"
}
```

Comment: Please include your code or error messages in your question, so StackOverflow can find similar question automatically and we copy-paste it to look for relevant information. Follow this link for more information: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors